# give information to/on a decision?

Tags: prepositions

> The purpose of data collection is to give valuable information **to/on** a future
>   pivot or persevere decision.

Is it *to* or *on*? Are both OK? Is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: You could give valuable information to somebody. It's just like saying, "give this to John". "John" here is the receiver of the object. So, in your case, you are giving information on something. "on" here is similar in meaning to "about".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BobRodes answer says, there is a difference in meaning for each.

An alternative construct is "The purpose of data collection is to give valuable information **for** a future pivot or persevere decision."

This is slightly vaguer than either "to" or "on", allowing it to provide for meaning either, or both.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight difference in meaning.  If you give the information *to* the decision, the decision itself is receiving the information.  If you give information **on** (which, as Cookie Monster says, is similar in meaning to "about") a decision, you are giving it to someone (or something) whose job it is to make the decision.

What you use is a matter of style.  *About* would be fine.  *On* is a bit less formal.  *To* is a bit unusual, and might be the sort of business jargon used by people who use "spend" and "ask" as nouns, and talk about pivot or persevere decisions.

Answer (score 1):

"to" implies that you're giving information and "decision" is receiving it which is irrational. In your sentence I would say "on" or "regarding".